# How to use JSON data in a nunjucks template?

Tags: nunjucks

js return list =

```
<ul><li data-name="{id:1,name:'a'}">a</li><li data-name="{id:2,name:'b'}">b</li></ul>
```

{{list|dump}}   Why does it show?

```
<ul><li data-name=\"[object Object]\">a</li><li data-name=\"[object Object]\">b</li></ul>
```

Comment: You must provide more code to get answer. Example don't convert `object` to `[object Object]`: `var nunjucks  = require('nunjucks'); var li = \`<ul><li data-name="{id:1,name:'a'}">a</li><li data-name="{id:2,name:'b'}">b</li></ul>\`; var res = nunjucks.renderString('{{ li | dump }}', {li}); console.log(res);`

Answer (score 0):

you can use [raw](https://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/templating.html#raw)
you can use a {% raw %} block and anything inside of it will be output as plain text.

Answer (score 0):

```
        Your code:
          <ul>
             <li data-name="{id:1,name:'a'}">a</li>
             <li data-name="{id:2,name:'b'}">b</li>
          </ul>

        Example:
            {%
            set list = [
            {name: 'a', id: 'yourId1'},
            {name: 'b', id: 'yourId2'}
            ]
            %}

            <ul>
               {% for item in list %}
                 <li data-name="{{item.name}}" id="{{item.id}}">{{item.name}}</li>
               {% endfor %}
            </ul>

        Output:
             <ul>
                 <li data-name="a" id="yourId1">a</li>
                 <li data-name="b" id="yourId2">b</li>
            </ul>
```